# Loading An XML File in HTML

Tags: html, xml, dynamic, playlist

I want to create a "playlist" feature for my personal web portfolio page.  iTunes can export a playlist in several file formats, but I presume XML would be the easiest to work with.

How can I load this XML file dynamically, and retain the same "tabled" formatting?  Is it possible?

As my playlist changes regularly, I'd like to keep updating this feature often, let's say weekly.  I would only have to export out a new playlist from iTunes and replace the linked XML file, refresh the HTML page and see a new, updated playlist.

Anyone?  Is this doable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the XML with an Ajax request and Integrate the parsed result into the Dom wrapped into a `<script type="text/xml">` Node.

There are Several javascript Widget libraries, some of them free for non-commercial use, which Accent XML structured as Data sources for ui components. Check Out [jqwidgets.com](http://jqwidgets.com) for example.

Depending on the complexity of the Layout you might be better Off Generating the final html Server-side, possibly as xhtml by means of XSLT. Note that an XSLT Transformation can also be Applied Client-side in modern Browsers.

Comment: Thank you, Collapsar.

I'm looking into this tutorial here:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp

And I created an account with jQuery UI Widgets, also.  I just have learn how to use these widgets to load an XML file.

I'll keep you posted and thanks again.